# SSMS and SQL Server : how to combine SELECT AS with SELECT =

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for zeroing prices for a supplier when they (or we) are late and the effective price date is past due.  The full code I'm working with is:

```
DECLARE @Today nvarchar(20) = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 101), 7, 4), '.', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 101), 1, 2), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 101), 4, 2))

SELECT --l.location_id
        im.item_id AS [Item ID]

        ,price1 = 0000.0000
        ,price2 = 0000.0000
        ,price3 = @Today

        ,im.price4
        ,im.price5
        ,price10 = @Today
        ,standard_cost = 0000.0000
        ,list_price = 0000.0000
        ,cost = 0000.0000

FROM    p21_view_inv_mast im
JOIN    p21_view_inv_loc l ON l.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid 
                           AND l.location_id = 1 
JOIN    p21_view_inventory_supplier s ON s.supplier_id = l.primary_supplier_id 
                                      AND s.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid
WHERE   l.primary_supplier_id = 100592  --Suplier ID, change per supplier
        AND im.delete_flag <> 'Y'
        AND ISNULL(l.delete_flag, 'N') <> 'Y'
```

I want the code to work exactly the same except changing the column headers for price1 (to "Price 1"), price2 (to "Price 2"), and price3 (to "Price 3").

Comment: `SELECT price1 = 0000.0000`  doesn't "pull the price1 column and set the values to zero" - it just selects the literal 0000.0000 and aliases it as `price1`

Comment: Your request makes no sense. The syntax `SELECT A = X` is equivalent to `SELECT X AS A`. It doesn't do anything to (or with!) a column named `A` in the base table (if it exists) -- changing data can only ever be done with an `UPDATE`, not a `SELECT`.

Comment: So just change it to `SELECT [Price 1] = 0000.0000` - why do you need to also reference the column?

Comment: It is utterly unclear why `0000.0000 AS [Price 1]` or `[Price 1] = 0000.0000` wouldn't do what you want, even though you've rejected the former as an answer. Note that both syntaxes do the same thing (which is also why you can't combine them -- there's no need to name something twice).

Comment: What is the query you ultimately run, and what is the error you get? It is [irrelevant if the table contains a column named `Price 1`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b17593f9895111628bc9d94eb1e1b41), because this name is not *used* as a column reference. Maybe you just need *both* columns for your process to work -- `price1` and `[Price 1]`. If so, just duplicate the line.

Comment: This expression `price1 = 0000.0000` is defining an alias (price1) for a constant (0000.0000) which you likely assume will result in a specific datatype (not safe but not the main point). In what table is the column `price1` and what do you intend "0000.0000" to do in that line?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for `coalesce(price1, 0000.0000) as "Price 1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with data in a table, which I assume you are here, then you need an `UPDATE` to set the value before reading it again.

Option 1 - UPDATE / SELECT (2 statements)

```
UPDATE Table1 SET price1 = 0000.0000;
SELECT price1 as [Price 1] FROM Table1;
```

Option 2 - UPDATE / OUTPUT (single statement)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET price1 = 0000.0000
OUTPUT Inserted.price1 as [Price 1];
```

Assuming `price1` actually comes from a table called `Table1`, because your example does not provide that context.

Also note that this does not include a `WHERE` clause which you most likely do want in your real situation.

EDIT

If all you're doing is trying to do is hide your data and modify your column headers then you want to use column aliases like everyone's telling you in comments:

```
SELECT 0000.0000 as [Price 1],
       0000.0000 as [Price 2],
       [etc...]
FROM ....
WHERE ...
```

In your case:

```
declare @Today nvarchar(20) = concat(substring(convert(nvarchar,getdate(),101),7,4),'.',substring(convert(nvarchar,getdate(),101),1,2),substring(convert(nvarchar,getdate(),101),4,2))

select  --l.location_id
        im.item_id as [Item ID]

        ,0000.0000 AS [Price 1]
        ,0000.0000 AS [Price 2]
        ,price3 = @Today

        ,0000.0000 as [Price 4]
        ,0000.0000 as [Price 5
        ,price10 = @Today
        ,0000.0000 AS [Standard Cost]
        ,0000.0000 = AS [List Price]
        ,0000.0000 = AS [Cost]


from    p21_view_inv_mast im
        join p21_view_inv_loc l on l.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid and l.location_id = 1 
        join p21_view_inventory_supplier s on s.supplier_id = l.primary_supplier_id and s.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid


where   l.primary_supplier_id = 100592  --Suplier ID, change per supplier
        and im.delete_flag <> 'Y'
        and ISNULL(l.delete_flag, 'N') <> 'Y'
```

Comment: Perfect.  That answers my question!  Ofc I can change the table1 name as needed.  It's the update and select combo that I need to add.  I'm a SQL noob.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If this is the correct interpretation then it **can** be done in a single statement (via `update` with an `output` clause)

Comment: Actually, update seems to update the table permanently.  I'm not trying to update the table (i don't think), just update the values in the table.  Updated the OP to include the full code I'm trying to edit.  Just trying to set the column headers to what I need them to be for my excel file.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah yes, of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene See my edit

Comment: @squillman I was confusing updating the table, with updating the database.  I do want to update the table, it's just the database I'm worried about accidentally updating.  Your edit above works for the column headers.  Now I just need the udpate clause included so that all price1, price2, standard cost, list price, and cost values are "0000.0000"

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene I edited my edit.  See if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT 0000.0000 as [Price 1]
```

Comment: no, i'm selecting price1.  i'm just trying to select it as [Price 1] and have all the values in that column, for every row, say 0000.0000

Comment: @Sabatino If you want `[Price 1]` to be the same (`0000.0000`) on every single row, why do you need to mention the column at all? You're setting a constant value, it really doesn't matter what's in the underlying column, there doesn't even have to _be_ an underlying column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, for the excel sheet (i copy the table to an excel sheet to process in our ERP system), I need a column with the header "Price 1".  Going with what you said, I could just insert a column into the table with all those values.

Comment: @Sabatino And what error happens when you change `,price1 = 0000.0000` to `,[Price 1] = 0000.0000`? You can't just say it "produces errors" - you need to be specific and tell us what errors and where (SSMS? Excel? ERP? Somewhere else?). Is `0000.0000` supposed to be a _value_ or do you think that is supposed to specify a _format_?